# using appcmd to set physical path of a website

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-8, iis-8.5, iis-10

How can I use appcmd in IIS7 to set the physical path of a website?

Something like...

```
appcmd set site summit /[path='/'].path:c:\newpath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='My Site'].[path='/'].[path='/'].physicalPath:"c:\newpath"  /commit:apphost
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked for me...   appcmd set site /site.name:"site name" /application[path='/'].virtualDirectory[path='/'].physicalPath:"D:\newpath".  Yours might work as well!

Comment: @JohnLivermore you should accept the answer to close the discussion.